# SignIn / SignUp with Google auth code via REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social, spring-oauth2

I am working on the backend for our two applications, which require sign-in and sign-up with a google account via REST - SPA app in Vue and Angular app.

I am thinking about this flow:
[image]

1. User from SPA or mobile application will log in google auth server with his credentials
2. App receive auth code from google
3. App request for sign-in / sign-up with this code to our auth service
4. Auth service fetch information about the user from google by this token, and generate jwt token for our SPA / mobile app which return back

Can you tell me if Spring Social module provides some endpoints to handle and generate this tokens via REST or I must implement it by myself? Thank you.

Comment: I would not have the spa or mobile talk directly to google, because how are you supposed to keep the clientid and client secret in the client?

Comment: @Toerktumlare client id and secret will be placed in backend in my auth service. In SPA or mobile app user only sign in and get auth code, then I will send this code to my service with also has client id and secret and request google provider for signed in user profile (name, email, avatar, ...)

Comment: With Spring Security 5, Spring Social project has reached EOL. See https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/03/spring-social-end-of-life-announcement for details on that.
Spring Security 5 OAuth 2.0 Client module provides login capabilities to OAuth 2.0 compliant providers such as Google, GitHub, Facebook, etc.
You can check out Spring Security OAuth 2.0 login sample available at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login
Another helpful guide on this topic https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login